# Python をつかってMS Outlookのフラグがついているメールの題名を取得したい

Tags: python, excel, mail

現在Pythonにて日次更新するタスク管理表(エクセル)の自動化を試みています。その際、Outlookメールの受信トレイにフラグをまず手動でつけています。Pythonで試みたいのはその手動で付けたフラグメールの件名をコピーし、別で管理しているエクセル（タスク管理表）に貼り付けるという作業です。まずはエクセルのA1セルでいいので、そこに貼り付ける方法を教えていただけると助かります。Googleで調べましたがなかなかうまく検索で情報を得られませんでした。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

<現状できている部分>

```
import win32com.client
object = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
mapi = object.GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
print(inbox.Name)
```

<課題>

上記のコードから続けて、Outlookのフラグがついているメールを取得しエクセルに貼り付ける

Comment: どこまで出来ているか等が書いてあると回答が付きやすいでしょう。そもそもoutlookにアクセスするところからか、メール/件名取得まで出来ているのかとか。また出来ている処理があるなら、組み込みたい部分のソースコードがあると良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あまりoutlookは使用していないのですが、フラグというのは「TODOアイテムのフラグ」というもので良いのでしょうか？
あっているのであれば、下記のコードでメールの件名を取得できました。

```
import win32com.client
object = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
mapi = object.GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)

# 以下を追加しています。
for item in inbox.items:
    if item.IsMarkedAsTask:
        print(item.subject)
```

エクセルへの貼付けについては別途調べるなり、質問した方が良いかと思いますので割愛いたします。
（質問のタイトルにもありませんし。）

---

とか言いながら試してみたら簡単にできたので、Excelに出力部分も書いておきます。
（openpyxlは別途インストールしてください。）

```
import win32com.client
import openpyxl

INPUT_PATH = 'C:\\work\\20190204\\hoge.xlsx'
OUTPUT_PATH =  'C:\\work\\20190204\\hoge2.xlsx'
SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1'

object = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
mapi = object.GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)

# ブックを取得
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(INPUT_PATH)
# シートを取得
sheet = book[SHEET_NAME]

row_number = 1
for item in inbox.items:
    if item.IsMarkedAsTask:
        sheet.cell(row=row_number, column=1).value = item.subject
        row_number = row_number + 1
book.save(OUTPUT_PATH)
```

Comment: おそらく、フラグはこちらでしょう。[_MailItem.FlagStatus Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.flagstatus?view=outlook-pia), [OlFlagStatus Enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olflagstatus?view=outlook-pia) `olNoFlag`では無い(`olFlagMarked`と`olFlagComplete`の両方)とするか、`olFlagMarked` / `olFlagComplete`のどちらかのみ指定すれば、フラグが付いていると判断できるのでは？

Comment: 試した限りではうまく動いたのですが。。。あまりその辺り詳しくないので、使用する方はドキュメントを確認してからお願いいたします。尚、MailItem.IsMarkedAsTaskのドキュメントはこちらです。[MailItem.IsMarkedAsTask](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.ismarkedastask)